# operator[] of QVector returns incorrect value

Tags: c++, qt, copy, qvector

There are 4 examples of `QVector` and `operator=`:

```
auto value1 = (QVector<int>() << 1)[0]; //value is 1 (correct)
auto &value2 = (QVector<int>() << 1)[0]; //value is -572662307 (incorrect)
const auto value3 = (QVector<int>() << 1)[0]; //value is 1 (correct)
const auto& value4 = (QVector<int>() << 1)[0]; //value is -572662307 (incorrect)
```

So, could you, please, explain these examples more clearly? As far as I get the idea it is something about "deep copy", which is created by one of `operator=`, but it's not fully clear for me.

Comment: It has nothing to do with deep copies or `operator=` – you have references to objects whose lifetimes have ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep copy has nothing to do with it. Copy on write mechanism (this is related to "deep copy") of `QVector` is completely transparent to you and doesn't impact your scenario. For now ignore this feature.

First of all take a look what is returned by [QVector::operator[]](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#operator-5b-5d).
It returns reference to element of `QVector`.

Now when you use `&` you are capturing reference to vector item.

Now `QVector<int>()` is a temporary object which live scope is limited to that line.
So just after semicolon, vector is destroyed and reference is pointing to none existing element of vector (since vector doesn't exists anymore).

This leads to undefined behavior and your bad luck didn't lead to an application crash.

One way to fix it is not to use temporary object.

```cpp
   QVector v;
   v << 1;
   auto value1 = v[0];
   auto &value2 = v[0];
   const auto value3 = v[0];
   const auto& value4 = v[0];
```

Now all references are pointing to values which are still alive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But there is something I can't understand - for some reason, all 4 cases work properly on Linux (gcc x64) and the problem is reproducible on Windows (MSVS) only?

Comment: undefined behavior means anything can happen: it can crash, it can give invalid value, it can seems to work ok, ... fly can come out of your nose ;). If you enable address sanitizer or use Valgrind proper error should be reported by those tool.s